# Play framework storing Akka actors in collections

Tags: scala, playframework, akka

I'm creating WebSocket actors in Play (Scala).

Actors are being created somewhere else in the system, and I just need to keep them in one place, grouped by some variables.

What is the best practice to store them, and which one takes up the smallest amount of memory:

- Seq[Actor]
- Seq[ActorRef]
- Something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should **NEVER** store actors - the only way to access actor should be through the `ActorRef`

There are few patterns/practices that you could use to find your actors.

First is `ActorSelection`, and it would require building right actor hierarchy. For instance, you have users split by geographical location, then you might want to have actor selections like

- /user/..../US/PA/18900/user1
- /user/..../US/PA/18900/user2
- /user/..../US/NJ/07000/user3

This way you could find all actors using selection with wildcard, although you will stick with just one property to filter them

The other way is to have data structure that would store all your flags/properties, for instance.

> case class UserRef(ref: ActorRef, name: String, country: String, zip: Integer, active: Boolean)

Then, your 'directory' will store them as a `users = List[UserRef]` and you will be able to query this structure with one pass using `users.filter(_.active = true)` or `users.find(_.name = "superuser")`